# Change UIImageView or UIImage width

Tags: ios, uiimageview, resize, uiimage

I have 2 images (280x20 px) with a solid color (green and orange) and I'm placing the orange behind the green one. What I want is to resize or stretch (downwards) in width the green one. I don't care about losing quality, the images are made of a solid color.

Why? They will represent data, if i have 50%-50% distribution i want the green one to be 140x20. That way we can understand with the visual help of the images (something like a bar graph) that both images have the same size. If the data is 75%-25% i want the green one to be (280*0.75) in width showing this time a 3:1 proportion. Notice I won't be resizing the orange image, she will rest behind the green one and the user will one see what the green one doesn't cover.

I have no problem making any calculations regarding proportion of the data. **My problem is handling the image scale/stretch/etc**. I've tried the following:

```
//imageView is the imageView representing the "green image bar"
UIImageView* imageView = (UIImageView*) [cell viewWithTag:202];
double scale = 0.75;
CGRect frame = imageView.frame;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, 280*scale, frame.size.height);
```

I used to have some progress by actually resizing the UIImageView, but the position was the same. Causing the image (now with a smaller width) to appear as it had "moved" to the right, **I want that image to stay with that left alignment as it originally had** but with a smaller width.

In the storyboard this is located inside a prototype cell, that is why I got the UIImageView by tag. Also tried almost every Mode (View->Mode in the attribute tab on the storyboard), currently have "Scale to Fill", not working at this moment.

Should I resize the UIImage inside the UIImageView? Should I resize the entire UIImageView? Hopefully somebody can help me with good practices on this, thanks! :D

PS: Would've posted some screenshots, not enough reputation though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just using solid colours, then simply use a `UIView` and set the `backgroundColor` property. Using an image for this purpose is unnecessarily complicating things, besides, a `UIImageView` is a subclass of a `UIView`, so the only added functionality is going to pertain to things you don't need.

So now that we've settled on using `UIViews` instead of images, you don't have to worry about the `UIViewContentMode` anymore (or the Scale to fill nonsense). Simply change the `size` and `origin` properties of your views accordingly.

An example of using Views instead of Images for this purpose: (I can't guarantee syntax as I'm not writing this from my Mac)

```
UIView *greenView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,280,20)];
UIView *orangeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,280,20)];

greenView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
orangeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

CGRect newGreenFrame = greenView.frame;
newGreenFrame.size.width = newGreenFrame.size.width * 0.75;

greenView.frame = newGreenFrame;
```

This is a good way of initializing and changing the frames of `UIViews`. There are other, shorter ways of doing it but this allows for easier-to-read code.